# How exactly does V8 if statement optimization work

Tags: v8

I was reading a bug report ["off by one in TurboFan range optimization for String.indexOf"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=762874) on the chromium forum.

I am confused about one part of the code

```js
var i = 'A'.repeat(2**28 - 16).indexOf("", 2**28);
i += 16; // real value: i = 2**28, optimizer: i = 2**28-1
i >>= 28; // real value i = 1, optimizer: i = 0
i *= 100000; // real value i = 100000, optimizer: i = 0
if (i > 3) {
  return 0;
} else {
  var arr = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4];
  return arr[i];
}
```

From what I know about the TurboFan compiler, it can remove redundant `if` statements.
What's the case with

```js
if (i > 3) {} else {}
```

If `i` is typed to always be 0, the `else` would be redundant. So how come this is even a bug?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the case with
> `if (i > 3) {} else {}`
> If `i` is typed to always be 0, the `else` would be redundant.

`0 > 3` is false, so the `else` would be the only *non-redundant* thing in that case:

```
let i = 0;
if (i > 3) {
  console.log("redundant, may be optimized out");
} else {
  console.log("executed!");
}
```